# In MIPS Assembly why do we use syscall? Why doesn't the program operate on the instructions given automatically?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

Since functions like 'li $v0,4' already tell the program to print a string, why is syscall necessary?

Comment: That just sets `$v0` to `4`. Only the OS invoked by the syscall will look at that and do whatever is necessary for the given function. There are many times when `$v0` happens to be `4`, and you are not trying to print a string.

Comment: @Jester okay, so syscall is basically a 'print to screen' ?

Comment: `syscall` invokes the OS. The OS then looks at the value in `$v0` and figures out what you want it to do.

Comment: MIPS or someone else may have defined some syscalls, but it is arbitrary, you can implement them to do whatever you want.  It simply provides a way to pass control to the system and have the system do something for you.  They are not required for bare metal you could just call functions to do the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`syscall` allows you to access the system library.  The instruction that you point out, `li $v0,4` is simply used to request that `syscall` perform the relevant operation.

This is a very common programming pattern. Rather than allow direct access to the physical devices, the kernel, operating at the highest privilege level, brokers access to the devices through `syscall`, `int 0x80`, `sysenter` or whichever mechanism is used for the architecture and operating system that you are working under. This helps the system to be more stable overall.

While you don't state what your actual platform/OS is, an example set of standard system calls for MIPS can be [found here](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html). If you look at it, you'll see that it allows for a number of operations with devices to which you otherwise would not have access:

1. print integer
2. print float
3. print double
4. print string
5. read int
6. read float
7. read double
8. read string
9. sbrk (memory allocation)
10. exit
11. print character
12. read character
13. Open - file, device, etc.
14. read from a file descriptor (previously opened with open)
15. write to a file descriptor (previously opened with open)
16. close - file, device, etc.

A platform may have as many or as few system library functions as are deemed necessary by the designers. You will find that this is true of Windows, Linux, BSD, Solaris, etc.